# From dataframe to array, by row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe "df", and I would like to transform it into an array BY ROW, for example:

```
> df
    x  y
1   1 21
2   2 22
3   3 23
4   4 24
5   5 25
6   6 26
7   7 27
8   8 28

#Into this array:

> array.df
 , , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   1   21   2   22
[2,]   3   23   4   24

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   5   25   6   26
[2,]   7   27   8   28
```

Can anyone help me with the code? Thanks.

Comment: array.df <- array(df ,dim = c(2,4,2)) but it doesn't work properly

Comment: Any help? Maybe with library(abind)??

Answer (score 1):

Quite an ugly solution, but it gets the job done. Maybe someone else has a better way of doing this. In the meantime, it should do.

```
install.packages("reshape2")
library("reshape2")

df

  x  y
1 1 21
2 2 22
3 3 23
4 4 24
5 5 25
6 6 26
7 7 27
8 8 28

myarray <- array(cbind(matrix(melt(t(df))[1:8,3],byrow = T, ncol = 4),matrix(melt(t(df))[9:16,3],byrow = T, ncol = 4)), c(2,4,2))

, , 1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1   21    2   22
[2,]    3   23    4   24

, , 2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5   25    6   26
[2,]    7   27    8   28
```

### I will try and explain:

The idea is to transpose the data frame with `t()` and then melt it using the `melt()` function from the `reshape2` package. Upon reshaping the data, you want to grab the 3rd column and then create two matrices from it by row. Then, you will need to `cbind` those matrices into one matrix. And finally, use that matrix to get the array you want with dimension `c(2,4,2)`.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another not so elegant solution:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:8, y=21:28)
vec <- as.vector(t(df))               # transpose df and then turn into a single vector 
arr <- array(vec, dim=c(4,2,2))       # create array with first 2 dimensions transposed
lis <- lapply(1:2, function(x) { t(arr[,,x]) }) # transpose the first 2 dimensions
array(do.call(cbind, lis), c(2,4,2))  # convert back to array format

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1   21    2   22
[2,]    3   23    4   24

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5   25    6   26
[2,]    7   27    8   28
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only the base package:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:8, y = 21:28)

array.df <- array(
  data = as.vector(t(df)),
  dim = c(4,2,2))

array.df <- aperm(a = array.df, perm = c(2,1,3))

print(array.df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of a simpler base R answer for this using some array manipulation:

```
apply(array(t(df), dim=c(4,2,2)), c(1,3), t)

#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1   21    2   22
#[2,]    3   23    4   24
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    5   25    6   26
#[2,]    7   27    8   28
```

Use some `matrix` trickery to fill by row and then reshape again. `sapply`'s `simplify="array"` ensures the `array` output:

```
sapply(
  split(df, rep(1:2,each=nrow(df)/2)),
  function(x) matrix(c(matrix(unlist(x),byrow=TRUE,ncol=2)),nrow=2), 
  simplify="array"
)

#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1   21    2   22
#[2,]    3   23    4   24
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    5   25    6   26
#[2,]    7   27    8   28
```